# Need help hosting my Class project to work with https://

Tags: ssl, https, hosting

I Uploaded my Project to Byethost.com which offer free https:// and SSL Certificate But when i go to my https://mydomain.byethost.com using chrome the https:// is mark(x) which is not trusted. so i tried to generate a new CSR for mydomain and try to get a new Free SSl certificate example rapidSSL free trial, I need to approve throught an email account but most of the email accounts they provided for approval are not known to me . How will i get them to sent to my gmail for approval :Plzz help

Answer (score 1):

Usually SSL providers send SSL verification email at mailboxes like webmaster, admin or hostmaster. If your SSL vendor allows, verification email can be send at either registrant email address, or admin email address. You must have either of these email addresses activated to receive the verification email. Some SSL providers also provide the file upload method for SSL verification wherein you have to upload the file provided by the SSL vendor.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is as u said The gave me to choose several emails including webmaster@,admin@, which i dont have access to . These emails id are below to the webhosting website i registered ? which means that they will get the email and verify the SSL for my domain.

Comment: i did one process where they gave me a file which they instructed to upload to the root directory of my website .